# Hidden input take space in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On [this page](http://www.makemeheal.com/pictures/brachioplasty/triple-b-a11488) at the bottom in the form to add comments, I have a set of hidden HTML inputs. Works fine, except on IE.

In IE, they take space and move the form down. I suspect it is because there are generic CSS rules for `input`, but I'm not 100% sure. If that's the case, how do I make it so that input types "hidden" don't get affected by CSS rules? If that's not it, then what's going on?

Comment: Just came across this, what I would do is use jQuery to add a class to `input[type=hidden]` and then set `.hidden` (assuming that's the class name) to `display: none;`. It should work but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE add conditional tags to handle `#content` and `.comment-sbt-btn`

Do this:

1. Remove `width: 100%` from `#content`
2. Clear left the and remove `margin-left` on `.comment-sbt-btn`:

> ```
>   clear: left; 
>   margin-left: inherit;
> ```

This will fix the rendering problem in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use IE Developer Tools( `F12` ) to find out which object is really taking space.

Comment: I used debugbar and it all points to the hidden input. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `float: left;`. It'll help.

Comment: How will it help? Answers should have an explanation

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me with a hidden submit button in IE

```
<input type="submit" style="width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;" />
```

Maybe it'll work for other types of hidden controls

Comment: Is there a way to do it globally via a CSS rules? Without writing a class name or modifying all the html across the site?

Comment: I'm sure you could either put a class on all the hidden inputs or apply the relevant CSS via jQuery